# Comparator (int) in inner class

Tags: java

I have some problem with comparator. I make very simple class with 2 fields and i need make inner classes with comparators for this two fields.

```
public class KlassA {

    private int i;
    private String tekst;  

    public int getI(){
        return i;
```

This comparator works ok.

```
   public static class KomparatorText implements Comparator<KlassA>{
        public int compare(KlassA a1, KlassA a2) {
            return a1.getTekst().compareTo(a2.getTekst());
        }

   }
```

In this comparator i have some issue: "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int"

```
   public static class KomparatorI implements Comparator<KlassA>{
        public int compare(KlassA a1, KlassA a2) {
            return a1.getI().compareTo(a2.getI());
        }
   }
```

I also try CompareTo but then i need to implements field or method and it's not work

```
   public static class KomparatorI implements Comparable<KlassA>{

        private int i = this.i;

        public int compareTo(KlassA o) {
           if (this.i < o.i)
              return -1;
           else if (this.getI() == o.getI())
              return 0;
           else
              return 1;
       }
   }
}
```

I really don't know how to fix it. I'm already serach the other inquiries but all sollutions don't work for my example. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force everything to Integers as in the other answers, but, IMO, better to keep your current class structure with ints and to use a built in method, [Integer.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int))

```
public static class KomparatorI implements Comparator<KlassA>{
   public int compare(KlassA a1, KlassA a2) {
      return Integer.compare(a1.getI(), a2.getI());
   }
}
```

Likewise, if you wish to use Comparable instead, use it to save typing (and avoid mistakes in the logic):

```
public static class KomparatorI implements Comparable<KlassA>{
   public int compareTo(KlassA o) {
      return Integer.compare(this.i, o.i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wanted to add this, but you were faster than me

Comment: @user2610529 Happens to me a lot too, being a couple a minutes late...  :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is so simple but so usefull :)

Comment: Hmmm one more issue, when i put Your code for compareTo:

 public static class KomparatorI2 implements Comparable<KlassA>{

     public int compareTo(KlassA o) {
         return Integer.compare(this.i, o.i);
      }
 }

I have message: "i cannot be resolved or is not a field"
I need to make field: private int i; but it's not will work?

Comment: The code to implement Comparable should generally be within the actual KlassA class, and it will have access to `o.i`.  But, if you are elsewhere, use `o.getI()` to use the public method.

Comment: It's the same resault. I need to create local function getI();
 
  public int compareTo(KlassA o) {
 
         return Integer.compare(this.getI(), o.getI());
      }

  private int getI() {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
   return 0;
 
  }

In Outer class getI(); is public of course but it's shouldn't be problem for inner class.

Comment: See my comment above.  In general, a *separate class* (possibly inner) implements `Comparator`.  But the *class itself* (in your case, `KlassA`) implements `Comparable`.  That way it has access to the fields.  For example, Integer implements Comparable itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, primitive types like `int`, `float`, or `boolean` are not objects like the correspondent `Integer`, `Float`, or `Boolean`.This means you cannot call methods on them.

Try using,

```
Integer.valueOf(this.i).compareTo(o.i);
```

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that the compiler tries to covert primitive types to their corresponding object classes automatically. In the sample above this happens for the argument `o.i`, which is converted automatically to an `Integer`.
Try searching for "java autoboxing".

*Note*: You can actually use `Integer.compare(this.i, o.i)` which is better, for that case.

Answer (score -1):

Lets see what you gout here

```
a1.getI().compareTo(a2.getI());
```

it looks like `getI()` returns `int` insteed of `Integer`.

Change mehod definition to return `Integer` insteed and all wil be fine. So inside your `KlaasA`

`public Integer getI(){ return i};`